# Invalid Client in IdentityServer4 in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 for authentication and I have a client as a console application.

I set the config in IdentityServer as follow:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "online.console.client",
    ClientName = "backoffice",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".ToSha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        "webapi"
    }
}
```

And the client calling IdentityServer like here:

```
private static async Task<TokenResponse> RequestTokenAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5001");
    if (disco.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception(disco.Error);
    }

    var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
    {
        Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

        ClientId = "online.console.client",
        Scope = "webapi",
        ClientSecret = "secret".ToSha256()
    });

    if (response.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception(response.Error);
    }

    return response;
}
```

The reponse has error:

> fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
>
> ```
>   Client secret validation failed for client: online.console.client.
> ```

Where is my problem?
I guess the client has wrong config.

Answer (score 0):

In the client it's not required to call ToSha256 for ClientSecret. You start true in server config but next do false for client. so all that is need to do:

```
ClientSecret =  "secret"
```